# Postgresql - 2 DB servers with a view on both that returns same columns. how to combine into 1 table

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 different postgres servers, a 9.4 and a 9.6 version. I have a view (with many joins) for both of them that return the exact same column 'names' but don't share common a common schema. I would like to have 1 DB with 1 table or a table on the 9.6 server that combines the data from both views. Data cannot be static when queried. I have read up on postgres_fdw, but it doesn't seem like it will work with what I need.

Answer (score 0):

postgres_fdw is part of the answer.  You can define a foreign table which references a view.

Then you can create a view which merges the two things:

```
create view combined as select * from localview union all select * from foreign_table;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! won't be able to try this until next week some time; will reply back after I return to the office.